# Should off-topic, meta comments about a question being in the sidebar be discouraged?

Tags: discussion, comments, hot-questions

More and more often, I'm seeing comments along the lines of, "your question's title caught my attention in the sidebar," or, "[I'm surprised this has just shown up on my "Hot Network Questions" [...]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/260824/why-am-i-feeling-funky)," that don't otherwise contribute to the question, and don't attempt to answer it.

Should such comments be discouraged, or can they be considered harmless?

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, go ahead and flag those as noise.